# Best optimizer to minimize Connectionist Temporal Classification (CTC) loss in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, speech-recognition, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am currently trying to minimize the ctc loss from a bidirectional RNN(LSTMCell), for speech recognition. I am using the MomentumOptimizer to do this as it was used in an example I referred, but neither do I have theoretical backing on why I'm using it nor do I know if this is the best optimizer to use to update the weights. A sample code of how I am computing the loss and optimizer is given below.

```
loss = tf.nn.ctc_loss(outputs, targets, seq_len)
optimizer = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(learning_rate, Momentum).minimize(tf.reduce_mean(loss))
```

Please let me know if there is a better optimizer I can use.

Comment: You'll need to experiment. The most popular are `Momentum`, `Adam`, and `AdaGrad`. Unfortunately there is no good way. Generally these optimizers will reasonably on a wide range of problems, but there's no substitute for trying out all hyperparameters.

Comment: I achieved best results with RMSPropOptimizer(0.001) for a text-recognition task. Of course this does not mean that it works well for other tasks such as speech recognition.